# Definition of IFS and IFS=

Tags: linux, unix

What is the difference between IFS and IFS=?
I have read on the internet but the definitions are quite vague.Can someone please explain me?

Comment: `IFS=` sets the `IFS` value to empty string

Comment: Please post your question at [Unix & Linux StackEx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions) to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Internal Field Separator (IFS) that is used for word splitting after expansion  and IFS= assign empty value to IFS.  You can get more detailed understanding about IFS on https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS.